# Quarkus register for reflection external POJOs

Tags: native, quarkus, graalvm

i have an external lib with POJOs (about +100). I want to register all for reflection as i will use it on my rest client.

Is there a way to RegisterForReflection a whole package ? Should i do it programmatically ReflectiveClassBuildItem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no GraalVM configuration or Quarkus build item that allows a complete package to be registered